# Doubts over internet Radio Application in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i am trying to develop sort of internet radio application,i dont have any ideas of how to approach it.I surfed a lot,but i cant identify information to lead me to the right direction.

While surfing i came to know abt, player that they use to access shoutcast broadcast on their BB?

I came to know abt this [link](http://code.google.com/p/chaudcast/)

so guys any ideas,how can it be used for developing the application.So Hoping for some results

Answer (score 0):

Taking a close look at the source code for the application you linked to is a great start in understanding how to do streaming audio on the BlackBerry.  They implement a custom SourceStream and DataSource and use those to feed audio data from the network into a Player instance.

The best source for information is the BlackBerry Developer website.  There, you can find guides such as the [Audio and Video Playback](http://na.blackberry.com/developers/resources/C10_Audio_And_Video_Playback.pdf) guide, which goes over this in great detail including code samples.